# Unable to load CSS in Spring Mavenized project

Tags: java, css, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a problem with CSS path in my project. 
This is the file structure of a Spring Maven project.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbzpf.jpg]

In jsp page I wrote:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Treninky/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

But it still does not work. I can't find a solution.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: usually the css files are in resources? where are you keeping them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and it's better to move your css to another directory like `src/main/resources` or somewhere that not in WEB-INF

Comment: Thanks. There was a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Resources under WEB-INF directory are not visible outside the application.  You should have your /css directory straight under your webapp directory in order for it to be visible.

Something like

```
src/
   /main
        /webapp
               /Treninky
                        /css/*.css
```

And then your /css directory would be reachable

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to put your `css` file under `css` folder inside `src` folder:

```
Treninky >
         src >
              css/bootstrap.css
```

Then you can use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Treninky/src/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Flelix good advice
Best practice to get path of any folder from the project is: (as per flelix advice structure),

```
<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="<%=request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath()%>/src/css/bootstrap.css">
```