# How to fix unable to load css file in maven build on maven springmvc project

Tags: java, css, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I create a search application in maven springmvc. when run it on terminal is shows the following error:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.0.2:war (default-war) on project search-qc-ui: Could not explode webapp... Unable to open file /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/Myproject/styles/classadmin/sss.css for writing. -> [Help 1]

I also referenced it on the below link but I am not able to fix it.Is anyone knows it pleaselet me know as soon as possible.

[Unable to load CSS in Spring Mavenized project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848126/unable-to-load-css-in-spring-mavenized-project)

Comment: This looks suspiciously like you're trying to explode a WAR into a system-wide Tomcat installation without the appropriate privileges.

Comment: Thanks for your advise it works successfully.i was delete the previous build war file in webapps folder then build the project once again it works greate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delet the previous build war file in webapps folder. then build the project once agin it will works correctly.